# Peer-to-peer - informations about downloading

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, block, network, protocol

I would like to know how the software downloads the blockchain. If the bytes write throught the socket and wait until it's written. And If the software asks 16 blocks to each peer in which you're connected to ?

Best whiches.

Comment: Does this topic perhaps answer your question? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/111908/5406

Comment: Hi, I read this topic thanks to you ^^. Tell me if I got wrong but, does the software asks 1 peer only => 16 blocks or does the software share the ask of 16 blocks to 10 peers.
I don't fully understand this part of the topic. Thank you to had answer me.

Comment: It will request 16 blocks from each peer it has a connection to.

Comment: Thanks, I close the topic!

Comment: @Murch Is it requesting N blocks from *inbounds* connections ?

Comment: During IBD the node will only make connections to outbound peers and not advertise its own IP address, so it will not gain any inbound connections. While you generally can receive block and transaction data from either type of connection, we will generally try to only synchronize from outbound peers (i.e. peers that permit inbound connections).

Answer (score -1):

It will request 16 blocks from each peer it has a connection to. The bytes are written normally. The blocks download is doing via get_blocks et answer blocks message. Thanks for the Murch’s answer.